# Android preferences do not seem to be persisted between application starts

Tags: android, android-preferences

I'm using preferences to save some user settings in my Nexus 7 app.  My code for saving a value to preferences is:

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    String systemId = spinnerActivity.getSelectedItem().toString();
    editor.putString(PreferenceKeys.SAVED_SYSTEMID, systemId);
    if (!editor.commit()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error saving System ID", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

I've stepped through this with the debugger and it is being called correctly.  When I restart my app. and try to read back the value with the code below, I always get null.

```
     SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
     String savedSystemId = sharedPref.getString(PreferenceKeys.SAVED_SYSTEMID, null);
     ConnectionInfo.setSystemId(savedSystemId);
```

The loading is called from the onCreate() function in the main activity.  Strangely enough loading of other preference values elsewhere in the app. works fine, it's just this one case that doesn't work.  Can anyone see what's wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you're saving the value you think you are?

Comment: Yes I've stepped it through in the debugger very closely, a value of null is never saved.  I've stepped it saving a valid value.  On restarting the app. I always read back null however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("Name_of_item",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

Comment: Use that to replace the save part of your code and the retrieve part of your code.

Comment: Bingo you got it.  I needed to call sharedPreferences instead of Preferences.  It was using the class name as the first arg, which was different between classes of course.

Comment: Awesome. Lucky Guess. Glad I can help

Answer (score 1):

please try the below

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences("preference_name",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
String systemId = spinnerActivity.getSelectedItem().toString();
editor.putString(PreferenceKeys.SAVED_SYSTEMID, systemId);
if (!editor.commit()) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error saving System ID", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}



SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences("preference_name",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 String savedSystemId = sharedPref.getString(PreferenceKeys.SAVED_SYSTEMID, null);
 ConnectionInfo.setSystemId(savedSystemId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Try to use this:

```
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
```

Or, you can use a named preferences page in which case:

```
public static final String PREF_FILE_NAME = "PrefFile";
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
```